# Если авторизация по ключу не проходит, авторизоваться с другим пользователем

Tags: linux, unix, ssh

Хочу реализовать следующий алгоритм авторизации по SSH:

1. Попробовать авторизацию по ключу с пользователем `username`.
2. Если не получилось, сразу начать авторизацию по паролю как `defaultuser`.

Такой алгоритм должен работать для всех хостов в некоторой подсети.

Можно ли реализовать это с помощью конфигурации SSH или отдельного инструмента? Если этот путь вообще не годится, неэффективен или небезопасен — расскажите, как правильно, такой ответ меня тоже устроит.

---

Немного о контексте. Есть подсеть, в которой я разворачиваю виртуальные машины. Только что созданные доступны по дефолтному пользователю и паролю. После этого я создаю на них своего пользователя с sudo-правами, добавляю публичный ключ. Хочу, чтобы авторизация всегда проходила с первой попытки.

Ничего не приходилось бы настраивать, если бы `$(whoami)` и `defaultuser` совпадали.

Comment: А что мешает создать своего пользователя, докинуть свой ключ и поправить sshd_config на этапе постран скриптов или вообще в файле ответов? Какие виртуалки разворачиваются? Бубен, центось, сюся?

Comment: @donRumata постран скрипты не смогу поменять, т.к. использую PaaS. Что такое «файл овтетов» даже не знаю — подскажете, где почитать?

Comment: @donRumata виртуалки — мне только Debian & Ubuntu бывают нужны.

Comment: *я создаю на них своего пользователя* — вы это вручную делаете, или процесс автоматизирован?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin автоматизирован с помощью `debops bootstrap` ([документация](https://docs.debops.org/en/latest/debops-playbooks/docs/guides/getting-started.html#bootstrap-a-new-host)). Доступ по паролю все-таки пока не запрещаю, но буду.

Comment: https://www.debian.org/releases/wheezy/s390/apbs04.html.ru - для deb-based, http://pykickstart.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ , https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kickstart - redhat-like.

Comment: `ansible`, который вы упомянули ниже должен уметь разворачивать всё сам с нужными ключами и пользователями. Вместо `ansible` можно `puppet`. Кому что нравится.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

можно, например, такой shell-функцией-обёрткой воспользоваться (без первой и последней строки превращается в shell-скрипт):

```
sshwrapper() {
  if [ $# -ne 1 ]
  then
    echo "ожидаю один аргумент"
    return 1
  fi
  if ! ssh -o passwordauthentication=no $1
  then
    ssh -o passwordauthentication=yes defaultuser@$1
  fi
}
```

это только концептуальная заготовка. реализована лишь проверка на количество аргументов. подразумевается, что аргумент всего один — имя машины, куда пытаемся подключиться.

делается две попытки подключения. первая — по имени текущего пользователя (или сконфигурированного через `~/.ssh/config`) и **с запретом на аутентификацию по паролю**. если попытка оказалась неудачной, делается вторая попытка, с пользователем `defaultuser` и уже с явным разрешением на аутентификацию по паролю.

p.s. старался выдержать синтаксис posix-совместимым.

Comment: Забыл уточнить: SSH чаще пользуется ansible, чем я сам. Видимо, мне придется размещать содержимое этой функции где-нибудь в `/usr/local/bin/`, чтобы перекрыть основной SSH. Выглядит хрупко.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, малознаком с ansible. ему разве нельзя указать, какую программу следует использовать вместо `/usr/bin/ssh`? кстати, в таком случае надо будет устраивать полноценный синтаксический разбор опций/параметров, чтобы найти первый параметр (с именем хоста) // «хрупко» — в каком именно месте?

Comment: Но в целом это ответ. Конфигами решить нельзя, можно написать скрипт.

Comment: Хрупко именно в том, что нужно делать разбор параметров и вообще писать и поддерживать код. Вот что придумал: для ansible я могу задать нужного пользователя конфигами самого ansible, а сам буду использовать вашу функцию.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, кстати, а ansible сам по себе умеет использовать пароль только в том случае, если по ключу «не пустили»?

Comment: Кажется, нет. Если соединение по ключу неуспешно, он «проваливает» выполнение задачи для конкретного хоста. Можно заранее указать параметр `--ask-pass`, чтобы он запросил ввод пароля. Наверное, так сделано, чтобы не вводить пароли «на ходу». Управляемых хостов может быть много, вводить пароль для каждого — нерационально. То есть предполагается, что мы уже перед запуском знаем, какой способ авторизации является верным.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, а как же вы собирались «прикручивать» к ansible такой вариативный способ подключения? ну, если бы нашлась подходящая настройка для ssh. // я это спрашиваю не из праздного интереса: скоро самому придётся ansible осваивать, и, вероятно, использовать примерно в тех же сценариях, что и у вас.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60051/discussion-between-nick-volynkin-and-alexander-barakin).

Answer (score 1):

Можно поправить ssh_config, задав в нем отбор хостов по маске и для этих хостов задать User defaultyser

Comment: Можно, и у меня сейчас уже есть эта настройка. Но она не позволяет использовать своего пользователя и ключ для тех хостов, которые я уже «присвоил». Конфиг просто об этом не знает. А хосты я могу создавать и удалять каждый день, так что руками править конфиг — не вариант.